# git send-email unknown option --transfer-encoding

Tags: git, email

I am trying to send patches using `git send-email`. I have attachments which I want to send as plain text. I am trying to use the `--transfer-encoding` option. However, I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: unrecognized argument: --transfer-encoding=7bit
format-patch -o /tmp/cPcJzwsREr --transfer-encoding=7bit: command returned error: 128
```

Edit:
It seems to be a version problem. The option is not available for `v1.9.1`. But it is available for `v2.7.4` of `git-email` package.

I am trying to send a series of patches which have to be threaded with different subject prefixes for each mail. I am trying to use the `--chain-reply-to` and `--in-reply-to`. I am executing the following commands:

```
    git send-email --to=<email> --suppress-cc=self --transfer-encoding=7bit --compose-encoding=7bit ./patches/<patch_1>
    git send-email --to=<email> --suppress-cc=self --transfer-encoding=7bit --compose-encoding=7bit --chain-reply-to --in-reply-to=<message_id_of_previous_mail> ./patches/<patch_2>
    git send-email --to=<email> --suppress-cc=self --transfer-encoding=7bit --compose-encoding=7bit --chain-reply-to --in-reply-to=<message_id_of_previous_mail> ./patches/<patch_id>
```

I expect the emails to show up as:

```
Mail 1
|--> Mail 2
     |--> Mail 3
```

However I get 3 different mails in my inbox. The values in angular brackets are placeholders and I have actual values in their place while executing commands. Can you please help me?

Comment: What makes you think there is a `--transfer-encoding` option? See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html

Comment: What is the full command you are using? Please edit it into the question.

Comment: (I should add, `git send-email` *does* have `--transfer-encoding`, but `git format-patch` does not.  So as @halfer says, we need to see what you're actually *running*.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a transfer-coding for send-email, but only since Git v2.3.0-rc0 (Dec. 2014)

See [commit 8d81408](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d8140843501107c92e2f9a5acb60ee136352c1f), [commit bb29456](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb29456c89599acfc3ef3046e6a55ce0f48c9865) (25 Nov 2014) by [Paolo Bonzini (`bonzini`)](https://github.com/bonzini).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2374f1d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2374f1dfd12542d171b60065dc139a96cb0efe29), 22 Dec 2014)</sup>

> "`git send-email`" learned "`--transfer-encoding`" option to force
>   a non-fault Content-Transfer-Encoding header (e.g. base64).

In your case, it would even be easier with Git 2.19 (July 2018)

See [commit fa29f36](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa29f36d990df8cd42f323847245ab2ae0f0ae62), [commit e67a228](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e67a228cd8afa7a645a321df90393deceaa57a0e), [commit f2d06fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2d06fb13fc93c50067e75768a89db098a3d1809), [commit 7a36987](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a36987ffffa59052723ed7299c1de25bc18048a) (08 Jul 2018) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7633ff4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7633ff48ed3ee942cb9c1d233b41ef3a2676cb8a), 24 Jul 2018)</sup>

> The content-transfer-encoding of the message "git send-email" sends out by default was 8bit, which can cause trouble when there is an overlong line to bust RFC 5322/2822 limit.
>
> A new option '`auto`' to automatically switch to quoted-printable when there is such a line in the payload has been introduced and is made the default.

However, this has introduced some regression, and Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) will fix them.

Since "`git send-email`" learned to take '`auto`' as the value for the `transfer-encoding`, it by mistake stopped honoring the values given to the configuration variables sendemail.transferencoding and/or `sendemail.<ident>.transferencoding`.
This has been corrected to (finally) redoing the order of setting the default, reading the configuration and command line options.

See [commit 3ff1504](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ff15040e22676db0b369efbd8b908b8fcc9b38d), [commit 564eba4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/564eba4bc03325ac03c00b8769bd4a8414c4cc3b), [commit a8aea5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8aea5db7a174c29a34b2e1fad85aa2fcf33a687), [commit 2554dd1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2554dd1aa8ddbaa043cbd12da0ec7084a1413f37) (17 May 2019), and [commit 3494dfd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3494dfd3ee058bbeab6a462673d9184dcd694a8b), [commit e60f6d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e60f6d13f3b04ee3a8aa50ed5a0b97d2fb58bad8), [commit c573572](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c573572c52758c4368ebc410d6b801fefa6bcbdd) (09 May 2019) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 86d2271](https://github.com/git/git/commit/86d2271f06382ceeb66e891eff87166d858270e1), 13 Jun 2019)</sup>

Check in your case if the chaining works better with that latest version.

See also the examples of the latest  `In-Reply-To` fix from Git  v1.7.4-rc0 (Nov. 2010), where the initial `In-Reply-To` apply only to first email.

See [commit db54c8e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db54c8e710397fbd58892daead6181b424d6d70a) (12 Nov 2010) by [Antonio Ospite (`ao2`)](https://github.com/ao2).
See [commit 54aae5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54aae5e1a08cb8c788d6f7345ca29898a5941140) (19 Oct 2010) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0153043](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01530432f73e7a29fbb9c4bc62aa88fba125ca7d), 24 Nov 2010)</sup>

```
--in-reply-to=<identifier>::
```

> Make the first mail (or all the mails with `--no-thread`) appear as a reply to the given Message-Id, which avoids breaking threads to provide a new patch series.
>
> The second and subsequent emails will be sent as replies according to
>   the `--[no]-chain-reply-to` setting.